# parse a delphi text , Access violation with function call

Tags: delphi

I wanted to parse a ASCII Text for all occurences of e.g. ( bla, bla, bla ), text inside brackets using the following code

```
function FilterText(const Source, TagStart, TagEnd: string): TstringList;  overload;
var StartPos, EndPos: integer;

begin
  result.Clear;
  try
    StartPos := PosEx(TagStart,Source);
    while StartPos > 0 do
      begin
        inc(StartPos,Length(TagStart));
        EndPos := PosEx(TagEnd,Source,StartPos);
        result.Add(Copy(Source,StartPos,EndPos - StartPos));
        StartPos := PosEx(TagStart,Source,EndPos + Length(TagEnd));
      end;

  finally

  end;
end;
```

I call this function using the following code

```
 memo1.Lines.AddStrings( FilterText(memo1.Lines.Text,'(',')'));
```

Instead of returning all text between brackets I get an AV .... why ????

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line:

```
result.Clear;
```

Calls a method on an unitialized variable of type `TStringList`. That leads to undefined behaviour. In your case it seems that manifests as an access violation.

You could instantiate the string list inside `FilterText`, and so avoid the AV.

```
function FilterText(...): TStringList;
begin
  result := TStringList.Create;
  try
    ....
  except
    result.Free;
    raise;
  end;
end;
```

But that leaves you with a bigger problem. Who is going to take ownership of the object? You use the function like this:

```
memo1.Lines.AddStrings(FilterText(memo1.Lines.Text,'(',')'));
```

Since your design has `FilterText` returning a new string list object, nothing takes ownership and therefore you leak.

You could do it like this:

```
FilteredText := FilterText(...);
try
  memo1.Lines.AddStrings(FilteredText); 
finally
  FilteredText.Free;
end;
```

Since `FilterText` is instantiating a new object and expecting the caller to take ownership, it would be prudent to give it a name to indicate that ownership transfer. For example, you might call the function `CreateFilteredText`.

---

Another option would be to expect the caller to instantiate the string list, and pass that object to `FilterText`. I personally find that approach to be a little easier to understand.

That version might look like this:

```
procedure FilterText(..., FilteredText: TStrings);
begin
  ...
  Strings.Add(...);
  ...
end;
```

And from the caller's side:

```
FilteredText := TStringList.Create;
try
  FilterText(..., FilteredText);
  memo1.Lines.AddStrings(FilteredText); 
finally
  FilteredText.Free;
end;
```

Comment: You could even skip the separate string-list object and call `FilterText(..., Memo1.Lines)`.

Comment: @Rob I had though about that too. But I noted that the user is using the same `TStrings` instance for input and output. So I thought that might be a little confusing.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to create Result (TStringList).
You can also use TStrings (more general type than TStringList) argument instead of result like

```
procedure FilterText(const Source, TagStart, TagEnd: string; AStrings: TStrings);
```

so external code will responsible both for creation and for deletion of list.

Answer (score 1):

Your function returns a TStringList, but never creates it. (It clears it instead, which is not necessary.)

```
begin
  Result := TStringList.Create;
  ...
end;
```

I personally don't like this, as it means the memory is allocated in the function but has to be freed by the code calling it. I prefer to have the stringlist passed in as a parameter to the function instead, so that it's clear that the caller both has to allocate it and free it.